# Python - override inherited method (changing part of internal method code)

Tags: python, overriding, odoo

There is this long method:

```
def get_payslip_lines(self, cr, uid, contract_ids, payslip_id, context):
    def _sum_salary_rule_category(localdict, category, amount):
        if category.parent_id:
            localdict = _sum_salary_rule_category(localdict, category.parent_id, amount)
        localdict['categories'].dict[category.code] = category.code in localdict['categories'].dict and localdict['categories'].dict[category.code] + amount or amount
        return localdict

    class BrowsableObject(object):
        def __init__(self, pool, cr, uid, employee_id, dict):
            self.pool = pool
            self.cr = cr
            self.uid = uid
            self.employee_id = employee_id
            self.dict = dict

        def __getattr__(self, attr):
            return attr in self.dict and self.dict.__getitem__(attr) or 0.0

    class InputLine(BrowsableObject):
        """a class that will be used into the python code, mainly for usability purposes"""
        def sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
            if to_date is None:
                to_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            result = 0.0
            self.cr.execute("SELECT sum(amount) as sum\
                        FROM hr_payslip as hp, hr_payslip_input as pi \
                        WHERE hp.employee_id = %s AND hp.state = 'done' \
                        AND hp.date_from >= %s AND hp.date_to <= %s AND hp.id = pi.payslip_id AND pi.code = %s",
                       (self.employee_id, from_date, to_date, code))
            res = self.cr.fetchone()[0]
            return res or 0.0

    class WorkedDays(BrowsableObject):
        """a class that will be used into the python code, mainly for usability purposes"""
        def _sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
            if to_date is None:
                to_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            result = 0.0
            self.cr.execute("SELECT sum(number_of_days) as number_of_days, sum(number_of_hours) as number_of_hours\
                        FROM hr_payslip as hp, hr_payslip_worked_days as pi \
                        WHERE hp.employee_id = %s AND hp.state = 'done'\
                        AND hp.date_from >= %s AND hp.date_to <= %s AND hp.id = pi.payslip_id AND pi.code = %s",
                       (self.employee_id, from_date, to_date, code))
            return self.cr.fetchone()

        def sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
            res = self._sum(code, from_date, to_date)
            return res and res[0] or 0.0

        def sum_hours(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
            res = self._sum(code, from_date, to_date)
            return res and res[1] or 0.0

    class Payslips(BrowsableObject):
        """a class that will be used into the python code, mainly for usability purposes"""

        def sum(self, code, from_date, to_date=None):
            if to_date is None:
                to_date = datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            self.cr.execute("SELECT sum(case when hp.credit_note = False then (pl.total) else (-pl.total) end)\
                        FROM hr_payslip as hp, hr_payslip_line as pl \
                        WHERE hp.employee_id = %s AND hp.state = 'done' \
                        AND hp.date_from >= %s AND hp.date_to <= %s AND hp.id = pl.slip_id AND pl.code = %s",
                        (self.employee_id, from_date, to_date, code))
            res = self.cr.fetchone()
            return res and res[0] or 0.0

    #we keep a dict with the result because a value can be overwritten by another rule with the same code
    result_dict = {}
    rules = {}
    categories_dict = {}
    blacklist = []
    payslip_obj = self.pool.get('hr.payslip')
    inputs_obj = self.pool.get('hr.payslip.worked_days')
    obj_rule = self.pool.get('hr.salary.rule')
    payslip = payslip_obj.browse(cr, uid, payslip_id, context=context)
    worked_days = {}
    for worked_days_line in payslip.worked_days_line_ids:
        worked_days[worked_days_line.code] = worked_days_line
    inputs = {}
    for input_line in payslip.input_line_ids:
        inputs[input_line.code] = input_line

    categories_obj = BrowsableObject(self.pool, cr, uid, payslip.employee_id.id, categories_dict)
    input_obj = InputLine(self.pool, cr, uid, payslip.employee_id.id, inputs)
    worked_days_obj = WorkedDays(self.pool, cr, uid, payslip.employee_id.id, worked_days)
    payslip_obj = Payslips(self.pool, cr, uid, payslip.employee_id.id, payslip)
    rules_obj = BrowsableObject(self.pool, cr, uid, payslip.employee_id.id, rules)
    baselocaldict = {'categories': categories_obj, 'rules': rules_obj, 'payslip': payslip_obj, 'worked_days': worked_days_obj, 'inputs': input_obj}
    #get the ids of the structures on the contracts and their parent id as well
    structure_ids = self.pool.get('hr.contract').get_all_structures(cr, uid, contract_ids, context=context)
    #get the rules of the structure and thier children
    rule_ids = self.pool.get('hr.payroll.structure').get_all_rules(cr, uid, structure_ids, context=context)
    #run the rules by sequence
    sorted_rule_ids = [id for id, sequence in sorted(rule_ids, key=lambda x:x[1])]

    for contract in self.pool.get('hr.contract').browse(cr, uid, contract_ids, context=context):
        employee = contract.employee_id           
        localdict = dict(baselocaldict, employee=employee, contract=contract)
        for rule in obj_rule.browse(cr, uid, sorted_rule_ids, context=context):
            key = rule.code + '-' + str(contract.id)
            localdict['result'] = None
            localdict['result_qty'] = 1.0
            localdict['result_rate'] = 100
            #check if the rule can be applied
            if obj_rule.satisfy_condition(cr, uid, rule.id, localdict, context=context) and rule.id not in blacklist:
                #compute the amount of the rule
                amount, qty, rate = obj_rule.compute_rule(cr, uid, rule.id, localdict, context=context)
                #check if there is already a rule computed with that code
                previous_amount = rule.code in localdict and localdict[rule.code] or 0.0
                #set/overwrite the amount computed for this rule in the localdict
                tot_rule = amount * qty * rate / 100.0
                localdict[rule.code] = tot_rule
                rules[rule.code] = rule
                #sum the amount for its salary category
                localdict = _sum_salary_rule_category(localdict, rule.category_id, tot_rule - previous_amount)
                #create/overwrite the rule in the temporary results
                result_dict[key] = {
                    'salary_rule_id': rule.id,
                    'contract_id': contract.id,
                    'name': rule.name,
                    'code': rule.code,
                    'category_id': rule.category_id.id,
                    'sequence': rule.sequence,
                    'appears_on_payslip': rule.appears_on_payslip,
                    'condition_select': rule.condition_select,
                    'condition_python': rule.condition_python,
                    'condition_range': rule.condition_range,
                    'condition_range_min': rule.condition_range_min,
                    'condition_range_max': rule.condition_range_max,
                    'amount_select': rule.amount_select,
                    'amount_fix': rule.amount_fix,
                    'amount_python_compute': rule.amount_python_compute,
                    'amount_percentage': rule.amount_percentage,
                    'amount_percentage_base': rule.amount_percentage_base,
                    'register_id': rule.register_id.id,
                    'amount': amount,
                    'employee_id': contract.employee_id.id,
                    'quantity': qty,
                    'rate': rate,
                }
            else:
                #blacklist this rule and its children
                blacklist += [id for id, seq in self.pool.get('hr.salary.rule')._recursive_search_of_rules(cr, uid, [rule], context=context)]

    result = [value for code, value in result_dict.items()]
    return result
```

I need to override that method, adding some modifications for this method. The simplest way would be to just copy everything and then modify what I need, but maybe there is better practice than that? If I use `super`, I won't be able to modify internal code, only add some modifications before `super` method will be called, but I need to modify what is inside (and needed modifications are not related with input parameters for that method).

To be exact I need to add this code:

```
duration = 0.0
tsheet_obj = self.pool.get('hr.analytic.timesheet')
timesheet_ids = tsheet_obj.search(cr, uid, [('employee_id', '=', employee.id), 
    ('date', '>=', payslip_obj.date_from), ('date', '<=', payslip_obj.date_to)])
for tsheet in tsheet_obj.browse(cr, uid, timesheet_ids):
    duration += tsheet.unit_amount
```

And then modify this line, adding key/value pair (for duration):

```
 localdict = dict(baselocaldict, employee=employee, contract=contract, duration=duration)
```

And this modification should be added just after this part of the code:

```
'''
for contract in self.pool.get('hr.contract').browse(cr, uid, contract_ids, context=context):
            employee = contract.employee_id
'''
```

P.S. And I can't just simply modify original method, because I need to use OOP principles and not directly modify base method.

Comment: The whole definition of classes and submethods within a method's scope already beats the purpose of OOP. Can you move the classes and submethods outside of the method? Can you move the part you need to change to an additional submethod? Then you can override only the relevant part.

Comment: @Korem I can't directly modify anything in this method. It's a frameworks standard method. If I would modify it, after next framework code update, my code would be just lost.

Comment: You need the duration in the localcontext so that you can use the duration value in the salary rules. right? Or is there any other functionality with this duration?

Comment: @OmaL Yes. I need to implement duration 'keyword' (if we could call that), so in salary rules, it could calculate payslip from timesheet activities. Everything works with my code, its just kind of bad to copy everything, but I don't see (or don't know) any other way how to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

I have an alternate solution for you. In salary rules you can have different objects like contract, employee, payslip etc. So what you need to do is to create a method any of the classes(employee, payslip, contract etc) and call that method inside the rule. For example you have defined a method called `calc_duration` in hr.employee which returns the duration. So in salary rule you need to call it as `employee.calc_duration()`,If you need and extra arguments other than cr, uid, ids, that can also be passed.